# Plot patches of same (visual) size on logarithmic scale

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, logarithm

I would like to mark some peaks in a graph which has a logarithmic x-axis. I was thinking of using `patch` since I need a callback that responds when the user clicks on the marker. The `Vertices` property of `patch` is in units of data, not pixels. However, I'd like the patches to appear with the same visual width and height, but I cannot find a way to compute the width (in units of data) that leads to the same width (in pixels).

I thought it could not be too complicated, but I got totally stuck and maybe tried too much to see the easy answer.

I know this is not purely related to Matlab, but I'm happy to use something else than `patch`, as long as it provides the functionality to respond on a mouse click.

```
peakpos = [50 500 5000];
peakheight = [5000 7500 10000];

x = 0:5e4;
y = zeros(numel(x),1);
for k = 1:3
    y(peakpos(k)) = peakheight(k);
end

ax = axes(figure());
plot(ax, x,y);
ax.XScale = 'log';
ax.Units = 'pixels';

dataperpx_y = diff(ax.YLim)/ax.Position(4);

ax.YLim = [0 1e4+30 * dataperpx_y];
ax.NextPlot = 'add';
for k = 1:3
    patch(ax, ...
        'Faces', [1 2 3], ...
        'Vertices', ...
            [ x(peakpos(k)) peakheight(k)+5*dataperpx_y
              x(peakpos(k)) - 25 peakheight(k)+15*dataperpx_y  
              x(peakpos(k)) + 25 peakheight(k)+15*dataperpx_y 
            ], ...
        'ButtonDownFcn', @(h,e)display(h.Vertices));
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, as I thought, it was not too complicated. I do not know where exactly I got stuck, but one thing which was a little bit confusing was that setting the `XScale` property of an axes to `log` makes the axes use decadic logarithms, while the `log()` function is the natural logarithm.

After plotting `log10(x)` at a linear scale, the solution was quite obvious:

```
peakpos = [50 500 5000];
peakheight = [5000 7500 10000];

x = 0:5e4;
y = zeros(numel(x),1);
for k = 1:3
    y(peakpos(k)) = peakheight(k);
end

ax = subplot(2,1,1);

plot(ax, log10(x),y);
%ax.XScale = 'log';
ax.Units = 'pixels';

dataperpx_y = diff(ax.YLim)/ax.Position(4);
dataperpx_x = diff(ax.XLim)/ax.Position(3);
ax.YLim = [0 1e4+30 * dataperpx_y];
ax.NextPlot = 'add';
for k = 1:3
    patch(ax, ...
        'Faces', [1 2 3], ...
        'Vertices', ...
            [ log10(x(peakpos(k))) peakheight(k)+5*dataperpx_y
              log10(x(peakpos(k))) - 5*dataperpx_x peakheight(k)+15*dataperpx_y  
              log10(x(peakpos(k))) + 5*dataperpx_x peakheight(k)+15*dataperpx_y 
            ], ...
        'ButtonDownFcn', @(h,e)display(h.Vertices));
end

ax = subplot(2,1,2);

plot(ax, x, y);
ax.XScale = 'log';
ax.Units = 'pixels';
dataperpx_y = diff(ax.YLim)/ax.Position(4);
dataperpx_x = diff(log10(ax.XLim))/ax.Position(3);
ax.YLim = [0 1e4+30 * dataperpx_y];
ax.NextPlot = 'add';

for k = 1:3
    patch(ax, ...
        'Faces', [1 2 3], ...
        'Vertices', ...
            [ x(peakpos(k)) peakheight(k)+5*dataperpx_y
              x(peakpos(k)) / 10^(5*dataperpx_x) peakheight(k)+15*dataperpx_y  
              x(peakpos(k)) * 10^(5*dataperpx_x) peakheight(k)+15*dataperpx_y 
            ], ...
        'ButtonDownFcn', @(h,e)display(h.Vertices));
end
```

[image]